# archive a directory and its content to a zip archive

Tags: zip

I ran

```
zip book my/
```

it created a zip file `book.zip`, but with only `my/` as its content, and nothing under its `my/`, but there is content under `./my/`. I wonder how I can zip it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip -r book my/`

`-r` stands for recursive.

`man zip` (or `zip -h` in case man pages are not available in your system) may help you understanding other useful options as well.